# Spring Security 4 to secure simple page without coding not working in Tomcat

Tags: spring-security, tomcat8

I had made a simple project using Spring Security to secure a simple page.

You can download the project from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1JEA0VK1xPld3JhMFJfZDVyams/view).

Here is my `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="true" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Spring Security Example</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <description>Spring Security filter</description>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and `spring-security.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <!--chnage enabled to activate funtionality,-->
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="disabled" secured-annotations="disabled" jsr250-annotations="disabled"/>
    <http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none"/>
    <http use-expressions="true"  disable-url-rewriting="true"  create-session="always" auto-config="false">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" requires-channel="any"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" requires-channel="any"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="any"/>
        <form-login/>
        <http-basic />
        <logout />
        <session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession"/>
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
        <headers>
            <cache-control/>
            <content-type-options/>
            <frame-options/>
            <hsts disabled="true"/>
            <xss-protection/>
        </headers>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext"/>
            <user-service>
                <user name="john" password="smith" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Under Maven environment, run:

```sh
mvn jetty:run
```

goes fine.

When I package it and put it into Tomcat 8/9, it just gotta HTTP 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please delete the default servlet mapping. and it will work.

```
<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```